# Mirror Javascript Variable Changes

Tags: javascript, object, reference, pass-by-reference

I am trying to create an object relationship in which object2's `nextString` property would mirror any change to object1's `originalString`.

```
var object1 = {
    nestedObject: {
        originalString: "old"
    }
}
var object2 = {
    nextString: object1.nestedObject.originalString
}
object1.nestedObject.originalString = "new";
```

originalString now is "new" but nextString is still "old"

I have read that this is due to the copy of the string which is made as JS does not use pass-by-reference as a language like C does.

With the sample relationship between object1 and object2 above, is there a way to accomplish what I would like?

Comment: Programming side effects in this way is a really bad idea. Have you considered simply creating an object to consolidate and carry your active state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does use pass by reference, however when you do `originalString = "new"`, you're actually assinging a new reference to `originalString`, so it's no longer pointing at the `old` value.

What you can do instead is hold a reference to the `nestedObject`, because the object is not being reassigned, only the string within.

```js
var object1 = {
    nestedObject: {
        originalString: "old"
    }
}

var object2 = {
    // Hold a reference to the nestedObject
    nestedObject: object1.nestedObject,
}

// Assign a new value
object1.nestedObject.originalString = "new";

// Both objects will reflect the change
console.log(object1.nestedObject.originalString);
console.log(object2.nestedObject.originalString);
```